Problems with syntax for Google Sheets Query
I am trying to create a template in Google Sheets to simplify my workflow breaking down movie scripts for my job as an Art Director. The project has one sheet called "SETCODES" (a master list of all Sets) and another sheet called "BREAKDOWN" where I will input all of the information.
My goal is to make the content in sheet "BREAKDOWN", Column A automatically populate based on the set selected in Column B (a dropdown referencing the list of sets the the sheet "SETCODES" (Column B). In an ideal world these would both be dropdown lists (columns A & B in BREAKDOWN sheet) where if you select either the Set Code or the Set Name the other would auto-populate, so I don't need to constantly go back to the Master Set List.
Apologies for my lack of technical knowledge. This seems like a good place to get the answers I need and I appreciate any help I can get! I've been at it for hours and tried way to many things without success. My latest attempt is to use the Query function, but I am getting multiply errors.
I've allowed edit access on the following sheet for anyone willing to help:
LINK TO PUBLIC/EDITABLE COPY OF SHEET:
I tried to use the following code in BREAKDOWN!A2:
=QUERY(SETCODES!A2:B,"Select A where B = '"&B2&"'")
I expected the cells to auto-populate as I select each Set Name, but it seems I am getting the error #VALUE for some rows and I am unable to select the same set multiple times (shows error #N/A).

Did you remove the public access? I was "kicked out" while editing it. I didn't manage to make screenshots of all the things I did but managed to write down most of them. Please take a look at my solution as well. I included the set color codes without the need to script anything (but it does a bit of copy-pasting, then again, you need to make a compromise if you want the best of both worlds). I made the changes in my own sheet to not ruin what you already had (first 30 rows).

Apologies for removing the Public access @TheNomad! I only noticed your work after removing access, but it was helpful to learn from your solutions.

This might involve a bit more work, but it might be closer to your requirements. This will also add some "restrictions" so that you don't mix&match cells.
I added a new sheet "BREAKDOWN_Nomad" to not ruin what you already have. I added a link to the sets and their codes, but that is decided strictly by the set name, not the code. This should be the logical choice since you might confuse or forget what B01 or C02 are, but will remember Patricia's House and whether it's inside or the exterior.
Next, to keep you from accidentally writing some wrong code or writing a code that might not match the actual set name I locked the column. And because you might want some sort of edit at some point, I did it with a warning (so you could edit it, if you really wanted to, but if you did it by accident, you can rollback.
Thirdly, I added colors based on your set's choices. I only did the first 30 rows though.
This should cover all of your requirements and I'll detail below how to do it, and the color part is without code. The only drawback is that when your first set-up the spreadsheet you'll have some manual work to do. But this should only be done once per movie (or at least, you can keep the color codes on the set sheet and just change the names to what match on another movie or based on your own personal "feelings". Indeed, to get the color auto-magically you'd prolly need coding, but the option I give you should be the best of both worlds without code or advanced technical stuff.
Technical notes (I have Google Sheets in a different language but I tried to translate the options as closely as possible so bear with me in case the menu or pop-up names don't exactly match)

read-only set codes


Select a sample range (you can change it later, don't worry), for example A2-A5, go to the Data menu and select Protected sheets and ranges. Add a description if you wish, select Range, you'd have the sheet's name (in my case BREAKDOWN_Nomad), then the operator ! and manuall type A1:A500 (or whatever range you wish).
Select Change permissions and choose Edit with warning
Click Finish


Color


Select the range of columns and rows you wish (in my examample A2:D30), go to the Format menu and select Conditional Formatting
Select the Single Color tab
Apply on the range you want (A1:D500 maybe), similar to the read-only setting; obviously if you only want the A and B columns to be colored, just type A1:B500
In the formatting rules choose Custom Formula
The value should be =INDIRECT(CONCAT("A", ROW()))="XXXXX" and instead of XXXX you set the rule for the set you wish (and yes, this is going to be the hamster-on-a-wheel work that you will manually do so if you have 300 sets, yup, you'll do 300 color rules; some ways to reduce this is by applying formulas that check the start or end of a string so if you have cases such as Connie's House with the Kitchen or Brianna's Bedroom, you can test if the value starts with "C02-" or other such tricks)
In the Style select the color that matches the one on the set sheet. Yes, manually select it like you did when you colored the set
Click Add a new rule and it will keep the current settings so all you have to do is change the set code and the color
Click Finish when you're done



You may try this for a general solution & for your idealistic output scenario, you could look into [google-apps-script]
=arrayformula(xlookup(B2:B,SETCODES!B:B,SETCODES!A:A,))



Thank-you @rockinfreakshow! this works perfectly for my needs. I think that the ideal solution is a little too advanced for me at this point.

Is there any way for the formatting to auto-populate as well? I colour code the set list and was hoping that colour coding would be also reflected in BREAKDOWN Column A.

not with formulas; again coding could help...
